# Updating Network Manager

Tags: networking, command-line, networkmanager

While fiddling a bit with Network Manager on my Ubuntu, I checked it's version with `NetworkManager -V` and it gave me **1.2.6**

From there I decided to look online what the most current versions where, and to my surprise, there have been a lot of others, with the most current being **1.8** if I am not mistaken.

So to update it, I tried the following:

**1)**

```
sudo apt update
```

**result:** Version stayed the same

**2)**

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install network-manager
```

**result:**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
network-manager is already the newest version (1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.0.4.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 97 not upgraded.
```

---

**QUESTION:** What might be the reason I am not managing to update my network manager? Am I not using the right command to get the new version? Might it be something else? The terminal said it's set to the newest version, but how can that be the case when googling online shows so many higher versions.

---

**UPDATED:** some extra info:

```
lsb_release -a
```

**gives:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: It is the newest version _for your packaged ubuntu release_.  Update your question to include the output of `lsb_release -a`.

Comment: @user4556274 updated

Answer (score 3):

Just because a software developer/author releases a newer version of some software, in your case `NetworkManager`, it does not mean that a distribution will choose to package and make it available on a particular version or even the latest version of their distribution.  It may be a "business" decision, lack of packaging and testing resources, dependency issues, or any one of a number of other reasons.

You can always download the source and build it yourself.

Comment: I see, so if I wanted to find out which version of Ubuntu (or other linux distro if ubuntu doesn't support higher versions), had support for versions 1.6 or higher of Network Manager, how might I be able to find that peace of info? I'm looking scavenging the internet as we speak, at least for me it wasn't as straight forward as googling for it sadly

Comment: You cannot take a package from another Linux distribution and just install it on your Ubuntu system.  In general, Linux is source code compatible, not binary compatible. Gnome utilities such as `NetworkManager` tend to be challenging to package due to fickle library dependencies.

Comment: @Webeng, given that 1.8 was only released about 2 weeks ago,  your best option might be to simply wait a few weeks to see if it is packaged for your distribution and version.

Answer (score 2):

The [NetworkManager-1.8.0](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/) isn't available on the regulary Ubuntu repository , you have the latest NM version installed : [1.2.6](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/network-manager)

Comment: Oh so if I wanted to have verion 1.6 or greater, does that mean I would need to get a new linux based operating system and supports those versions? Or when you said "regulary" does that mean that Ubuntu versions that aren't LTS releases (Long Term Support) do have the option for higher versions of NetworkManager?

Comment: @Webeng if you want the latest versions of almost any active open source package, you need to download the source and compile yourself.  Browsing the package listing GAD3R linked above, you can see that the near-future release Ubuntu 17.10 is only up to [NetworkManager 1.4.4](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/net/network-manager)

Comment: @Webeng compiling networkmanager from source need a  lot of dependencies , see here http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/networkmanager.html (the required and the recommanded)